# Mysql list tables and sizes - order by size

Tags: mysql

What would be the query to list all tables in a database order by their size in mysql?

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com/) See [ask advice](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask-advice), please.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get the sizes of the tables of a mysql database?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9620198/how-to-get-the-sizes-of-the-tables-of-a-mysql-database)

Comment: Check http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2008/02/04/finding-out-largest-tables-on-mysql-server/

Comment: Related, if it's of interest, I wrote a *Describe All Tables* in [this Answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38693721).

Answer (score 108, accepted):

Try this...

```
SELECT TABLE_NAME, table_rows, data_length, index_length, 
round(((data_length + index_length) / 1024 / 1024),2) "Size in MB"
FROM information_schema.TABLES WHERE table_schema = "schema_name"
ORDER BY (data_length + index_length) DESC;
```

Note: Replace `schema_name` above with the name of your database

Answer (score 8):

Run the following query in the mysql client

```
SELECT table_name AS "Tables", 
round(((data_length + index_length) / 1024 / 1024), 2) "Size in MB" 
FROM information_schema.TABLES 
WHERE table_schema = "$DB_NAME"
ORDER BY (data_length + index_length) DESC;
```

Answer (score -1):

Execute following query in information_schema database:

```
SELECT table_schema AS "Database name",
SUM(data_length + index_length) / 1024 / 1024 AS "Size (MB)" 
FROM information_schema.TABLES 
GROUP BY table_schema 
ORDER BY (SUM(data_length + index_length) / 1024 / 1024) DESC;
```