# How to calculate maximum memory needed for one row in a mySQL table

Tags: mysql

I need to write the SRS for my project in which I need to mention the amount of disk space taken by the database on the disk. For that I need to calculate the amount of disk space taken by a single row of a table. [image] For example if this is my table, how much disk space it takes for storing one record. So that I can estimate disk space need if there are 1 million users.

Is there any way to find it? Or should I need to calculate it manually??

Comment: Are you sure you are talking about memory here and not disk space?

Comment: Sorry, I need disk space only. Thanks for correcting.

Comment: ok, I see it is mysql. Have you seen this: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/14337/calculating-disk-space-usage-per-mysql-db

Comment: If you don't have a database yet, this may help you calculate the estimate usage: http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?10,267088,267203#msg-267203

Comment: Ya, I know that. But it is for calculating the disk space occupied. Here I need to estimate the disk space, so that I can mention that in SRS as the space required on disk for using my tool. (http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/14337/calculating-disk-space-usage-per-mysql-db)

Comment: ok, have a look at this: http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?10,267088,267203#msg-267203. Also, make sure you take growth into account - like how much it will grow per year - only you can estimate that.

Comment: Thankyou. I am calculating manually using the values given in that page. 'SHOW TABLE STATUS LIKE 'tablename'\G ' this is showing same data for all tables.

Comment: I guess it depends on the amount of data you have in there. Have you seen this too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9620198/how-to-get-the-sizes-of-the-tables-of-a-mysql-database