# How to find the size of each record in mysql? (liferay schema)

Tags: mysql, liferay

I am using `mysql`, I have `liferay` in that I have a table called holidays (it contains holiday dates of a particular month) and I want to find the size of each record in the holiday table.

For example:
`1aug2015-0.3MB..till 31aug2015.`

Comment: I am not sure its work or not . Check this -> SELECT LENGTH(`month`)/CHAR_LENGTH(`month`) kb FROM `holidays`

Comment: Thank you again, it is also giving the size of the table

Comment: I would remove the reference to Liferay, as this has nothing to do with it.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if there is a direct method to get a record/row size. But I think you can get the table size and divide it by the number of rows to get the average size of a record.

You may check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9620273/3332953) answer of [How to get the sizes of the tables of a MySQL database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9620198/how-to-get-the-sizes-of-the-tables-of-a-mysql-database).

Comment: thank you for the reply, I did the same thing, but there are some empty records in the table, so my teacher said that method is not correct for all records.