# Size of csv file data in mysql

Tags: mysql

We are deleting data from the EAV Table. We want to estimate how much of the data has been deleted from mysql table. As of now 20GB of data is deleted. Is it exactly equal to the mysql table data size or more/less ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9620198/how-to-get-the-sizes-of-the-tables-of-a-mysql-database

Comment: I know how to findout the sizes of the table. when you insert 20GB of data (using load command) into mysql, will the size of the table get increased or decreased ?

Comment: 1 select table size 2 delete data 3 select table size

Comment: until we run optimize on table, it will not claim the space back. I can do these steps. But before doing that, can we estimate the size of the table ?