# Is there a way to calculate total data size of column in MySql?

Tags: mysql

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9620273/1251549) is a solution how calculate table size, but what about column? Is there apporoach to calculate data which stored only for 1 column of table?

**Note**

The question is about *data* size, not data *type* size.

Answer (score 7):

You can use below query that will return data size in bytes:

```
SELECT sum(char_length(comment)) FROM tbl_comments
```

Comment: 1) it check only character data 2) I think index data should be added too.

Comment: This only returns the sum of the number of characters all strings in a column have. It is completely useless for numbers, dates, and other than string data.

Comment: And if even one row has NULL in this column then what?

Answer (score 2):

You can check in the storage requirements in the [reference manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/storage-requirements.html), and you can calculate your column size.

If you don't want to read too much, you can find some page, where is a collection about sizes and an online calculator:
[calculator](https://www.mysqldatatypes.com/)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: Cherry didn't describe specifically what type of column want to use.
I can copy-paste the entire reference manual, but it looks easier to link it.
Thanks your advice.