# Is it possible to know size of users?

Tags: mysql

My teacher is asking me for a query that should return the size (in mb or kb) that occupies all the users

By users I mean those accounts who have control over the DB,  like root.

Comment: How do *users* have *sizes*?  What actual data are you trying to measure?

Comment: I don't know..  The teacher is asking for that,  the only data the users have is the name of user,  where they can connect and privileges..  I don't think is possible what my teaching is asking

Comment: Your teacher is going to have to clarify what's actually needed here.  He/she may as well be asking for "the viscosity of the tables".  As currently stated, it makes no sense.

Comment: Possibly related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/9620198/319403