# How can I see the size of my django/python database or database tables?

Tags: python, django, sqlite

I would like to see the size of the database I created with django. This is for a project. 
How do I go about that? I have looked at stackoverflow answers, and I found this answer:

```
$ python manage.py shell

>>> import sys
>>> from myapp.models import MyModel
>>> my_model = MyModel()
>>> total_size = sys.getsizeof(my_model) * MyModel.objects.count()
```

This however always gives a size of 24 bytes, while the tables I put into it have completely different amounts of fields. I suspect this is wrong.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: with SQL you can check how many rows you have - but to get how many bytes it uses on disk you should rather find file with all data and check its size without using `Python`

Comment: using Google "mysql size on disk" I found SQL queries [MySQL / MariaDB: Show disk usage of tables and columns](https://makandracards.com/makandra/39413-mysql-mariadb-show-disk-usage-of-tables-and-columns) and [How to get the sizes of the tables of a MySQL database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9620198/how-to-get-the-sizes-of-the-tables-of-a-mysql-database)

Comment: Thank you for answering! I just saw I made a mistake, the database isnt't based on MySQL, it is instead based on sqlite3.

Comment: if it is sqlite then you should see file with data in django's project and check its size without django/python

Comment: I checked the size with sqlite analyzer from sqlite.org, but I get these values. I am unsure what they mean:
Percentage of total database......................  10.5%
Number of entries................................. 48
Bytes of storage consumed......................... 16384
Bytes of payload.................................. 1095
Since this is an entry to the table that uses multiple charfields and textfields 1095 seems really small. If I add 4 entries instead of 48 the storage consumed stays at 16384 which confuses me also. The documentation has made me none the wiser.

Comment: why don't you check normally file size on disk - ie. `print( os.stat(filename).st_size )`

Comment: Oh, so you can just check the file size of the 'db.sqlite3' file django makes and you get how much diskspace your database uses? I did not know that. Thanks!!

Comment: all databases keep data in some file - but only SQLite creates it in current folder and you can easily access it. For other databases you would have to find this file in different folder but if database is on other server then you may not have access to file.