# Size of a table in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have a table :

```
create table a(a1 int, a2 char(10),a3 float);
```

I can manually count the number of bytes allocated for this table a. But, how to find its size in mysql with some queries???

Comment: *I cam manually count the number of bytes allocated for this table a.* Really?

Comment: Yeah it's 4+4+10. 18 bytes

Comment: are you looking for total space taken by table a?

Comment: https://chartio.com/resources/tutorials/how-to-get-the-size-of-a-table-in-mysql/

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get the sizes of the tables of a MySQL database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9620198/how-to-get-the-sizes-of-the-tables-of-a-mysql-database)

Comment: *Yeah it's 4+4+10. 18 bytes* First, this is wrong. You have not taken a lot of bytes into account - nullability bytes and inner row number bytes at least. Second, the size of row is relative to the bytes allocated to a table very-very approximate. Third, the indices needs in a space also. And so on...

Answer (score 2):

IF you are looking for physical table size of table `a`

```
SELECT
  TABLE_NAME AS `Table`,
  ROUND((DATA_LENGTH + INDEX_LENGTH) / 1024 / 1024) AS `Size (MB)`
FROM
  information_schema.TABLES
WHERE
    TABLE_SCHEMA = '<schema>'
  AND
    TABLE_NAME = 'a'
ORDER BY
  (DATA_LENGTH + INDEX_LENGTH)
DESC;
```

Comment: ```SELECT   a AS `Table`,   ROUND((DATA_LENGTH + INDEX_LENGTH) / 1024 / 1024) AS `Size (MB)` FROM   information_schema.TABLES WHERE     TABLE_SCHEMA = "<schema>"   AND     TABLE_NAME = "a" ORDER BY   (DATA_LENGTH + INDEX_LENGTH) DESC;

ERROR 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 'a' in 'field list'
```
Reason for this error please.

Comment: Dude, I too had this doubt. I checked your edits. It displayed ```empty set```. What to do??? Any help??

Comment: It doesn't make sense. comment the --TABLE_SCHEMA part and change the TABLE_NAME part from equality to like operator so that you can make wider searchç